# Spring Boot JPA Uni directional one to one mapping with shared primary key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I would like to create two tables

1. employee - parent table
2. Address - child table

id on employee table is primary key and
address_id on address table is a foreign key.

**Save Operation**

```
{
    "name": "somename",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "address": "Some Address"
    }
}
```

I expect Hibernate to auto generate primary key and use the same primary key as address id in address table.
 
**Employee.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee{
 
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String name;
private int age;
 
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="addressId")
Private Address address;
}
```

**Address.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address{
 
@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer addressId;
private String address;
}
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>{
}
```

**EmployeeService.java**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService{
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
 
public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee){
return employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
}
```

[image]

I get the following error whenever I try to save
 
500 Internal Server Error

"message": "ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.example.demo.entity.Address; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.example.demo.entity.Address",

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work I think you need a model like this instead:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee{
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "employee")
    Private Address address;
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address{
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
    private Employee employee;
    private String address;
}
```